# How to Rewrite Vector Cross Product in Terms of Einstein's Notation?

Tags: vectors

How to rewrite this equation in terms of Einstein's notation?

$$\bf{A\times\nabla\times{A}}$$

Where $\bf{A}$ is a vector

Comment: What you wrote is not an equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\hat x_i \cdot \left(\vec A\times\left(\nabla\times\vec A\right)\right)&=\overbrace{\hat x_i \cdot \left(\hat x_jA_j\times \left(\hat x_k \times \hat x_\ell\frac{\partial A_\ell}{\partial x_k}\right)\right)}^{\epsilon_{ijm}\epsilon_{m k \ell }A_j\partial_kA_\ell}\\\\
&=\overbrace{\left(\delta_{j\ell}\delta_{ik}-\delta_{jk}\delta_{i\ell}\right)}^{\epsilon_{ijm}\epsilon_{m k \ell }} A_j\partial_k A_\ell\\\\
&=A_j\partial_i A_j-A_j\partial_j A_i\\\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\vec A\times\left(\nabla\times\vec A\right)=\frac12 \nabla |\vec A|^2-\vec A\cdot \nabla (\vec A)}
$$

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks!

Comment: @mvw Yes, thank you for catching that.  I've edited.

Comment: @achmed Thank you!  And you're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\left( A \times (\nabla \times A) \right)_i 
&= \epsilon_{ijk} A_j (\nabla \times A)_k \\
&= \epsilon_{ijk} A_j \epsilon_{klm} \partial_l A_m \\
&= \epsilon_{kij} \epsilon_{klm} A_j \partial_l A_m \\
&= (\delta_{il} \delta_{jm} - \delta_{im} \delta_{jl}) A_j \partial_l A_m \\
&= A_j \partial_i A_j - A_j \partial_j A_i \\
&= \left( \frac{1}{2} \nabla A^2 - (A \cdot \nabla) A \right)_i
\end{align}
where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the [Levi-Civita tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol).

Of course you could also mean

\begin{align}
\left( (A \times \nabla) \times A \right)_i 
&= \epsilon_{ijk} (A \times \nabla)_j A_k \\
&= \epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{jlm} A_l \partial_m A_k\\
&= \epsilon_{jki} \epsilon_{jlm} A_l \partial_m A_k\\
&= (\delta_{kl} \delta_{im} - \delta_{km} \delta_{il}) A_l \partial_m A_k\\
&= A_k \partial_i A_k - A_i \partial_k A_k \\
&= A_j \partial_i A_j - A_i \partial_j A_j \\
&= \left( \frac{1}{2} \nabla A^2 - A (\nabla \cdot A) \right)_i
\end{align}

Comment: How is this different from mine?  ;-))

Comment: Well, that is not different.  Rather, that is only a consequence.

Comment: Is there an error in mine?

Comment: Gimme some moments, I need to check all those tiny scripts at 200% zoom .. :-)

Comment: Now that was funny!